# How to restore boot from HDD when boot-repair fails?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manually fix a partition table ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48717/how-to-manually-fix-a-partition-table)

I can't boot to anything on my HDD, neither Windows nor Ubuntu.
I can, however, run Ubuntu from a LiveCD.

I tried using boot-repair but it cant repair anything, it just gives me this output:

> Please write on a paper the following URL:
>   http://paste.ubuntu.com/1566804/
>
> In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
>   boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.
>
> No change has been performed on your computer. See you soon!

How can I fix this so I can boot to my HDD partitions again?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your partition table: it indicates an initial partition size of 596.18 GB while your HDD seems to have a size of 320.1 GB. Hence why it complains with a message like "Partition outside the disk detected".

Repairing can't really help as the tool can't guess what your partition table should look like.

Reformatting will solve your problem, after which you can proceed with the reinstallation of your operating systems (good tip: install Windows first, then Linux).

You will physically lose all data on your hard disk though (even if it looks like there isn't much to lose anymore).