# Restoring a partition table using gdisk output

Tags: partitioning, gpt, fdisk, gdisk

I seem to have messed up the partition table of my mobile phone, and I was wondering whether I can recreate it from the `gdisk` output that I still have, using the Ubuntu installation on my laptop.

This is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sdb` before things went wrong:

```
Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 61071360 sectors, 29.1 GiB
Model: MMC Storage     
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 98101B32-BBE2-4BF2-A06E-2BB33D000C20
Partition table holds up to 36 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 10
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 61071326
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 257992 sectors (126.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1           32768          163839   64.0 MiB    0700  modem
   2          163840          165887   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  sbl1
   3          165888          166911   512.0 KiB   FFFF  dbi
   4          196608          197631   512.0 KiB   FFFF  DDR
   5          229376          231423   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  aboot
   6          231424          233471   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  rpm
   7          262144          294911   16.0 MiB    FFFF  boot
   8          294912          296959   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  tz
   9          296960          296961   1024 bytes  0700  pad
  10          327680          333823   3.0 MiB     FFFF  modemst1
  11          333824          339967   3.0 MiB     FFFF  modemst2
  12          339968          339969   1024 bytes  FFFF  pad1
  13          360448          393215   16.0 MiB    FFFF  misc
  14          393216          458751   32.0 MiB    0700  persist
  15          458752          491519   16.0 MiB    FFFF  recovery
  16          491520          497663   3.0 MiB     FFFF  fsg
  17          524288          525311   512.0 KiB   FFFF  fsc
  18          525312          526335   512.0 KiB   FFFF  ssd
  19          526336          526337   1024 bytes  FFFF  pad2
  20          526338          527361   512.0 KiB   FFFF  encrypt
  21          557056          573439   8.0 MiB     0700  drm
  22          573440          589823   8.0 MiB     0700  sns
  23          589824          655359   32.0 MiB    FFFF  laf
  24          655360          720895   32.0 MiB    FFFF  fota
  25          720896          786431   32.0 MiB    0700  mpt
  26          786432          787455   512.0 KiB   FFFF  dbibak
  27          787456          789503   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  rpmbak
  28          789504          791551   1024.0 KiB  FFFF  tzbak
  29          791552          791567   8.0 KiB     FFFF  rct
  30          819200         6488063   2.7 GiB     0700  system
  31         6488064         7733247   608.0 MiB   0700  cache
  32         7733248         7897087   80.0 MiB    0700  tombstones
  33         7897088         7929855   16.0 MiB    0700  spare
  34         7929856         8028159   48.0 MiB    0700  cust
  35         8028160        60948479   25.2 GiB    0700  userdata
  36        60948480        61071326   60.0 MiB    0700  grow
```

This is the output now:

```
***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 32 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sdb: 2014208 sectors, 983.5 MiB
Model: Mighty Drive    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F53C299E-4571-4252-8AAA-29494104F80C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 2014174
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1               2         2014207   983.5 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```

The output of `ls /dev/sdb*` only displays `/dev/sdb15` now, and nothing else. `/dev/sdb15` used to be the `recovery` partition in the output above, which I appear to have messed up, as well as the partition table, using `dd` with an invalid input file in conjunction with `of=/dev/sdb15`.

[Could this be the way to go](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48717/how-to-manually-fix-a-partition-table), using `fdisk`, putting it into sector mode with the `u` command, and then using `d` and `n` to delete and create the partitions on `/dev/sdb`?

I have already made some painful mistakes to get me into this mess, and I'm reluctant to mess things up any further before knowing exactly what to do (and why).

Comment: You seem to have corrupted your GPT partition table. How did you do that? It might be possible that you have corrupted your partitions as well. In that case, there is little benefit in recovering the partition table. Have a look at http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I had already come across that resource, but couldn't yet see how to make it work for me, that's why I posted here. Incidentally, it must have been some sort of problem with the phone, because sometime later I was able to see the partitions again. Bricked the phone anyway with further attempts to get it back to work ... =:-o